# How to get number of remaining keys in semaphore?

Tags: system-verilog

If declaring a semaphore in SystemVerilog using:

```
  semaphore sem = new(2);
```

Is there any way that a process can get information about the number of remaining keys in the semaphore?

There is no `num` method/attribute defined for the `semaphore` class, like there is for the `mailbox` class, which strikes me as odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the answer you would get from such a method is no longer valid as soon as returns. Management of semaphore keys is something you need wrap around its usage. A mailbox is one such example of wrapping queues and semaphores together.

IMHO, a semaphore is a base class level primitive that an end-user should never use directly.

Comment: The fact that the return value of such a method might be invalid as soon as it returns might be true in languages where true multi-threading is implemented, I don't see how this can happen in SystemVerilog. If there were a `get_num_keys()` function, this would return without passing control to any other thread and the return value would be valid in the function that called it.

Comment: @TudorTimi - except now we are beginning to see more multi-core implementation simulators out there.